# react-gtm-module not posting the event params

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager, facebook-pixel, google-pixel, react-gtm-module

I'm using `Google Tag Manager` to handle a Facebook Pixel.

That pixel should get fired through a Custom Event with custom params: { `make`, `model` } and custom conditions: { `make` equals `ford`, `model` equals `focus` }.

I have two basic implementations (each of them on its own project).

**On Project 1** I'm using JS Vanilla code and integrating `GTM` code as they recommend (updating head/body).

Then, when I call:

```
dataLayer.push({
  event: 'PageViewEvent',
  make: 'ford',
  model: 'focus',
});
```

The Trigger gets activated properly when the conditions match → **Success**.

**On Project 2** I'm using `NPM` package: `react-gtm-module`.

In order to use it I first initialize it with:

```
import TagManager from "react-gtm-module";

// ...

const tagManagerArgs = {
  'gtmId': gtmId,
  dataLayer: {
    'js': new Date(),
    'event': 'Initialize'
  },
  dataLayerName: 'MyCarDataLayer'
}

TagManager.initialize(tagManagerArgs);
```

and then I try to activate the trigger with:

```
import TagManager from "react-gtm-module";

// ...

const tagManagerArgs = {
  'gtmId': gtmId ,
  dataLayer: {
      'js': new Date(), // current date time,
      event: 'PageViewEvent',
      make: 'ford',
      model: 'focus',
  },
  dataLayerName: 'MyCarDataLayer' // must match the name specified in the TagManager.initialize() call
}

TagManager.dataLayer(tagManagerArgs);
```

but this time the trigger doesn't get activated.

When I check the status of the trigger that should get activated, I get the following:

[image]

where I can see that even the event name didn't match. It got as event name the current route but I specified as event: `PageViewEvent`.

On both examples I was using the same parameters. Then, I think I'm not using the `NPM` package: `react-gtm-module` properly.

Could you please, help me with this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I ran into a similar problem

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
import TagManager from "react-gtm-module";

// ...
TagManager.initialize({'gtmId': gtmId})

const tagManagerArgs = {
  dataLayer: {
      'js': new Date(), // current date time,
      event: 'PageViewEvent',
      make: 'ford',
      model: 'focus',
  }
}

TagManager.dataLayer(tagManagerArgs);
```

this answer is referenced from github issue https://github.com/alinemorelli/react-gtm/issues/28

scroll to the button, think they did some updates, so the answer from the top doesn't work anymore